# Val3 Programming Stäubli

Tags: encoding

can anyone help in the "FROMBINARY" in Val3 Prgramming? I want to send a number for example 3 from Python, but after sending the Number it is not converting it from  Binary to a number.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The "fromBinary" instruction in VAL 3 has 4 parameters. The first is a number of bytes in the data array you are converting. if you have only 1 byte of data it will be 1, if you have 4 bytes it will be 4. You may have more than 1 number in the array of bytes. The second parameter is how many number are in the array of bytes. So if you have three number each of which takes two bytes the first parameter will be 6 and second will be 3. if you have one number in a in a one byte array, then the first two parameters will be 1 and 2.

The third parameter is a format used to encode the number a single unsigned byte will have a format of "1". If the byte is signed (the first bit indicates positive or negative, it will be "-1". When there is more than one byte you have two methods commonly called big endian and little endian. in some case the most significant byte is first in other cases the least significant byte is first. so we have "2b", "2l", "-2b", and "-2l". There are also 4 byte encodings, "4b", "4l", "-4b", and "-4l".

For floating point single precision (4 bytes), we use "4.0b" and "4.0l". for floating point double precision (8 bytes), we use "8.0b", and "8.0l". floating point are always signed so we do add the "-"

The formats are strings, not numbers.

In you case if it is a single unsigned byte, use "1".

The final parameter is a numeric array holding the numbers from the array of bytes.

The instruction will return how many numbers were found.

So if your single unsigned byte is in variable, "nByte" and I want the number to go into the num variable "nNum" I do

fromBinary(nByte, 1, "1", nNum)

the instruction should return a 1 since it found 1 number.